# Get Ruby to identify if child process get a segfault

Tags: ruby, linux, segmentation-fault

I am running Ruby as a wrapper to an EDA tool, in RH5.
The tool segfaulted. However, the command line did not show any indication. Only when running the command that Ruby launched, did we learn that the segfault happened. How can I get the segfault message within the wrapper?
Thanks.

Comment: You should post some code, especially the ruby code you use as a wrapper.

Comment: Simply:system( "cck cmd.tcl")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Kernel#system documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> system returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false for non zero exit status. Returns nil if command execution fails. An error status is available in $?.

So, if you just want to make sure that everything went ok, you just check if the return value of `system` was `true`. If you want to specifically check if there was a segmentation fault, then the return value will be `false` and `$:` will be like this:

```
puts $?
#=> pid 3658 SIGSEGV (signal 11)
```